# PHP: Set index array based on other array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, indices

I have the following two hypothetical arrays:

```
$values = array("fourth", "first", "second", "third");
$indices = array(3, 0, 1, 2);
```

What is the fastest way to rearrange `$values` based on `$indices`?

Is there perhaps some way to do `$values->index_array = $indices`?

Comment: @Danack: when OP cannot express their thoughts - it's normal )

Comment: @zerkms your answer was correct and fast. Mine was correct but slower. Put it back and I'll upvote :)

Comment: It would help if you showed what the desired result is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do:

```
<?php
$newarray = array_fill_keys($indices, $values);
?>
```

This assumes your indices are always unique of course.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be exactly what I needed

Comment: I don't think this does what you want. It sets every element of `$newarray` to the same value.

Comment: It does do what he asked however.  Is it perfect?  Only the OP knows.

Comment: @bjørnSkagen: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: This results in a 2-D array, where each element is a copy of `$values`, and the keys come from `$indices`. How is that "rearranging $values"?

Comment: @Barmar: If you object to this answer, please ask the OP to clarify his question. Based on the logic in the original question this does do what the OP asked.

Comment: @bjørnSkagen As you've accepted this answer, please can you edit your question to say that this is what you wanted, as currently it doesn't read like that.

Comment: @Danack: it's so weird :-S

Answer (score 2):

It's just a guess based on a phrase from the question:

> way to rearrange $values based on $indices

```
$values = array("fourth", "first", "second", "third"); $indices = array(3, 0, 1, 2);

array_multisort($indices, $values);

var_dump($values);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/UKfNiq

Output is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "fourth"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  If any `$indicies` are out of order from the way PHP assigns array keys, the key value is lost.

Comment: @Phillip: it's OP's responsibility to guarantee they are in order. See: "rearrange $values based on $indices"

Comment: @zerms: Fair enough. This question sucks anyway. Time to be moving on.

Answer (score 0):

ZerkMS's answer is correct as defined by the question but you may be better off taking another approach to generating the results.

If you can, rather than generating two arrays of:

```
$values = array("fourth", "first", "second", "third"); 
$indices = array(3, 0, 1, 2);
```

instead just generate one array and call ksort on it:

```
$valuesToSort = array();
$valuesToSort[3] = 'fourth';
$valuesToSort[0] = 'first';
$valuesToSort[1] = 'second';
$valuesToSort[2] = 'third';

ksort($valuesToSort);
```